# After making an oath to try to not repeat a sin, I tried but repeated the sin; do I have to offer expiation?

Tags: tawba, oaths

I committed a sin a week or two ago, and I swore to Allah that I would try to stop it and I did try to stop but until not too long ago where I fell into sin.

Do I have to offer expiation for breaking that oath even though I have stopped myself from that sin before because I did try?

I'm not saying it was okay to sin.  Rather, is it another thing I have to offer expiations for?

Comment: See: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41165/repentance-in-islam

Answer (score 1):

**Answer is Yes.** That is the whole point of the oath.

When you took the oath, you took the responsibility of what it entails. If you wish to expiate for the oath, then there are means to do that. See: https://islamqa.info/en/search?q=oath+expiation

For the benefit of others and for yourself in future, it is inappropriate to take oaths to stay away from haram when Allah has already commanded you to stay away from haram. Adding an additional possibility of disobeying Allah (through making oaths which can be broken as happened in your case) is putting yourself in fitnah which is haram.

Answer (score 0):

> قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّـهِ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ جَمِيعًا إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ (الزمر/53)
>
> Say: O My servants! who have acted extravagantly against their own souls, do not despair of the mercy of Allah Surely Allah forgives the faults altogether Surely He is the Forgiving, the Merciful
>
> وَ لا تَیْأَسُوا مِنْ رَوْحِ اللّهِ إِنَّهُ لا یَیْأَسُ مِنْ رَوْحِ اللّهِ إِلاَّ الْقَوْمُ الْکافِرُونَ - (یوسف/87)
>
> Indeed, no one despairs of relief from Allah except the disbelieving people

You swore to Allah that you would try to stop it and you did try, so you don't have to offer expiation.

By the way, I think [this QA](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/41165/23264) would be useful too and we need Allah for everything in life not just certain things.

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا تُوبُوا إِلَى اللَّـهِ تَوْبَةً نَّصُوحًا عَسَىٰ رَ‌بُّكُمْ أَن يُكَفِّرَ‌ عَنكُمْ سَيِّئَاتِكُمْ - (تحریم/8)
>
> O you who have believed, repent to Allah with sincere repentance. Perhaps your Lord will remove from you your misdeeds

Allay says: تَوْبَةً نَّصُوحًا or "Sincere Repentance" which seems to have 4 conditions:
1. Abstaining the sin instantly
2. Istiqfaar (استغفار) which means asking Allah for forgiveness.
3. Heart regret. (this one is the most important one that will really helps)
4. Sincerely deciding to abstain the sin in future and do our best to not getting even near the sin.